# Database not showing

Tags: mysql, linux, connectivity, phpmyadmin

I create a database in the terminal linux ubuntu,gave it all privileges,created the table,inserted the rows.When I open phpmyadmin the database isn't showing how do I connect them?
I did use mysql -u root -p to open mysql.

Answer (score -1):

Answered in a comment by [Rick James](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/1876/rick-james):

phpmyadmin does not have permission to see that database.  Change it to use root.